# Disable animation when hiding/showing soft keys

Tags: android, android-keypad

I'm using the following method to hide the soft keys when I need to use the whole screen of a device:

```
private void hideSoftKeys() {
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
}
```

When I do, they hide with a sliding animation. Is there a way to make them vanish (and also appear) instantly?

Comment: Did you added android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" in your manifest ?

Comment: I don't mean the software keyboard, but the soft keys displayed on devices lacking the Back, Home and Menu keys. Also, I don't want to completely disable them for the activity (and I'm quite sure it can't be done easily), just hide and show them on demand. This I got covered. I'm just looking for a way to get rid of the sliding animation when they show and disappear.

Answer (score -1):

I know that it is little old question but do you try:

```
public void hideSoftKeyboard(View view){
  InputMethodManager imm =(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
  imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

it?

Comment: This will result in the same animating behavior